# Matlab Colorbar Formatting Numbered Ticks

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I am creating eight separate plots in matlab; both horizontal cross sections and vertical cross sections of a thunderstorm.  Since the horizontal cross section does not always contain the maximum return, the colorbar labels are different.  For example, my horizontal cross section will go from 0.0 to 0.4 whereas my vertical cross section will go from 0.0 to 0.7.  I have to put these plots on a poster I am presenting and the colorbars have to be the same.  Does anyone know how I can make the colorbar go from 0.0 to 1.0 by increments of 0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Use caxis to set the limits of the colorbar:

```
caxis([0 1]);
```

Then use ytick to set the interval of the colorbar by first getting it's handle:

```
h = colorbar;
set(h,'ytick',0:0.1:1)
```

Comment: @Jim Dont forget to accept the answer if you liked it! (small tick next to the number `0` in the answer.